# Android custom Expandablelistview does not trigger onChildClick

Tags: android

I'm beginner for android programming. I've download the code from http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com and works fine but the only problem is doesn't trigger the
onChildClick.

Here is the main activity

```
public class MenuCategory extends Activity {
        private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
        private List<GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
        ExpandableListAdapter adapter;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStater) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menucategory);

            prepareResource();
            initPage();

        }


        private void prepareResource() {
            String data = null;
            FileInputStream fIn = null;
            InputStreamReader isr = null;
            String response = null;
            String getParam = "?get=menuCategory";
            try{
                fIn = openFileInput("fromfile.dat");
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                int size = fIn.available(); 
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[size];
                isr.read(inputBuffer);
                data = new String(inputBuffer);
                isr.close();
                fIn.close();
                String[] dataSep = data.split("#");
                String Hs = dataSep[0];

                try {
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpGet(Hs+getParam);
                    String res = response.toString(); 
                    if(response.length()!=0){
                        mGroupCollection = new ArrayList<GroupEntity>();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        JSONArray eventArray = new JSONArray(res);
                        for (int i = 0; i < eventArray.length(); i++) {
                            jsonObject = eventArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            GroupEntity ge = new GroupEntity();
                            ge.Name = jsonObject.getString("Cat");

                            JSONArray abc  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("SubCat");
                            for (int j=0; j<abc.length(); j++){
                                GroupItemEntity gi = ge.new GroupItemEntity();
                                gi.Name = abc.getString(j);
                                ge.GroupItemCollection.add(gi);
                            }
                            mGroupCollection.add(ge);   
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            }
        }

        private void initPage() {
            mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
            adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);
            mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            registerForContextMenu(mExpandableListView);
        }
        public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
            String string = "Child Click";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, duration);
            toast.show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the Custom BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private ExpandableListView mExpandableListView;
    private List<GroupEntity> mGroupCollection;
    private int[] groupStatus;
    private int lastExpandedGroupPosition;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context pContext,
            ExpandableListView pExpandableListView,
            List<GroupEntity> pGroupCollection) {
        mContext = pContext;
        mGroupCollection = pGroupCollection;
        mExpandableListView = pExpandableListView;
        groupStatus = new int[mGroupCollection.size()];

        setListEvent();
    }

    private void setListEvent() {

        mExpandableListView
                .setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

                    public void onGroupExpand(int arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        groupStatus[arg0] = 1;
                        lastExpandedGroupPosition = arg0;
                    }
                });

        mExpandableListView
                .setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                    public void onGroupCollapse(int arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        groupStatus[arg0] = 0;
                    }
                });
    }

    public String getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.get(arg1).Name;
    }

    public long getChildId(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getChildView(int arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2, View arg3,
            ViewGroup arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ChildHolder childHolder;
        if (arg3 == null) {
            arg3 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_group_item, null);

            childHolder = new ChildHolder();

            childHolder.title = (TextView) arg3.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            arg3.setTag(childHolder);
        }else {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) arg3.getTag();
        }

        childHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.get(arg1).Name);
        return arg3;
    }

    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0).GroupItemCollection.size();
    }

    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mGroupCollection.get(arg0);
    }

    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mGroupCollection.size();
    }

    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    public View getGroupView(int arg0, boolean arg1, View arg2, ViewGroup arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GroupHolder groupHolder;
        if (arg2 == null) {
            arg2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_group,
                    null);
            groupHolder = new GroupHolder();
            groupHolder.img = (ImageView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.tag_img);
            groupHolder.title = (TextView) arg2.findViewById(R.id.group_title);
            arg2.setTag(groupHolder);
        } else {
            groupHolder = (GroupHolder) arg2.getTag();
        }
        if (groupStatus[arg0] == 0) {
            groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
        } else {
            groupHolder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
        }
        groupHolder.title.setText(mGroupCollection.get(arg0).Name);

        return arg2;
    }

    class GroupHolder {
        ImageView img;
        TextView title;
    }

    class ChildHolder {
        TextView title;
    }

    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition){
        //collapse the old expanded group, if not the same
        //as new group to expand
        if(groupPosition != lastExpandedGroupPosition){
            mExpandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedGroupPosition);
        }

        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);           
        lastExpandedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
    }
}
```

Item Group layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/group_header_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tag_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:src="@drawable/group_down"
        android:focusable="false"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/group_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#57810f"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:focusable="false"
         />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is the item child layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:paddingTop="5dip" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/groupItem"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/play_group_item"
        android:clickable="true" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:text="sample"
            android:textColor="#FFF38585"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:focusable="false"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

please help me

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code where you set the listener for child clicks to actually listen for those events.

Comment: when i add mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new onChildClickListener(){
   public boolean onChildClick( ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) {
          String string = "Child Click";
       int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
       Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, duration);
          toast.show();
          return false;
      }
  }); onCreate() it shows me the error on eclipse as onChildClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Manu I have also used same tutorial.Please tell me how perform action on child click.

Comment: I an using these codes expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
     int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   
    System.out.println("clicked..............."+groupPosition);
    Intent categoryList=new Intent(StatesScreen.this,CategoryList.class);
    startActivity(categoryList);
    return false;
   }
  });

Answer (score 14):

In adapter you have a method called isChildSelectable() witch return false, that's the problem. Change returned value to true to resolve problem.

Comment: This should've been made as the right answer a long time ago.. it's letting this inherited method go unnoticed that made me pluck all my hairs :P

Comment: It would be helpful if you picked a right answer, so it might also help others or share the solution that finally worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing this problem, onChildClick was not being trigger.

I found this comment:

> Solved, the problem is that if you have several textview's on the childview, the focusable property must be false (I don't know exactly why) adding android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" to the view solved the problem

on [Android ExpandableListView and onChildClick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19555364/3050951)

So adding `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` on childView worked for me.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Other common suggestions, such as setting isChildSelectable() to return true, were necessary but not sufficient to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is old thread, but if any one comes here to find answer, this is for them.
I found same problem when I used [this tutorial for expandable list view](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/) to make clickable child item just go to "main group item layout" (in my code it is list_group_item) and make linearlayout and textview clickable and facusable false.

Answer (score 0):

To set up the listener for child clicks you can do it like this in the `initPage` method(not `onCreate()`):

```
mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
            adapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this,mExpandableListView, mGroupCollection);
            mExpandableListView.setAdapter(adapter);
registerForContextMenu(mExpandableListView);
mExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                String string = "Child Click";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string,
                        duration);
                toast.show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @Manu And what does the error tells you? Are you sure you have the correct imports : `import android.widget.ExpandableListView;` and 
`import android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener;`?

Comment: Yes i have imported. But gives me error as: The method setOnChildClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener) in the type ExpandableListView is not applicable for the 
  arguments (new OnChildClickListener(){})
 - OnChildClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @Manu If you use eclipse, tryto delete all imports and then do `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `O` (**NOT** the number `0`, the letter O) and select the proper imports.

Comment: I have what you suggest and no error but the click event is not working. I debug it but no response on click listener

Comment: @Manu I guess placing that toast doesn't trigger? If this is the case then add the code for the adapter and the row layout.

Comment: i have added the custom adapter. please provide me the code how to.

Comment: @Manu I've asked you to also put the layout file for the child row. In that layout file, if you have elements like `Buttons`, `EditText`, `ImageButtons` add the attribute `android:focusable="false"` to them.

Comment: I have added the layout and the focusable attribute are also set but didn't work