# KOTLIN - expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener not working

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, expandablelistview

As my tilte, i have a `expandable listview`, but `setOnChildClick` event do not working, `setOnGroupExpandListener` `setOnGroupClickListener` being active. help me pls. thanks all !!!!

This is my code, fragment and adapter.

**Fragment:**

```
class DiscoverFilterFragment:Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentFilterDiscoverBinding
    private lateinit var filterAdapter : ExpandableListAdapter
    private lateinit var titleList : List<String>
    private lateinit var itemsList : HashMap<String, List<String>>
    private val viewModel: DiscoverViewModel by activityViewModels()
    var searchText : String = ""
    var authorText : String = ""
    var dateIssueText : String = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentFilterDiscoverBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        getDataFromApi(searchText, authorText + ",equals", dateIssueText + ",equals")
        onItemsClickEvent()
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    private fun getDataFromApi(searchText : String, authorText : String, dateIssueText : String) {
       titleList = ArrayList()
       itemsList = HashMap()

        viewModel.discoverFilter(searchText, authorText, dateIssueText)
        viewModel.getFilterObserverableItem().observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
            it?.let { it ->
                titleList = it.keys.toList()
                //Log.d("Title List","${titleList}")
                itemsList = it
                //Log.d("Title List","${itemsList}")
                filterAdapter = DiscoverFilterAdapter(requireContext(), titleList, itemsList)
                binding.expFilter.setAdapter(filterAdapter)
                (filterAdapter as DiscoverFilterAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }

    }

    private fun onItemsClickEvent() {
        val expandableListView = binding.expFilter
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener {
            Toast.makeText(
                activity,
                "Open"
                ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener {
                parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }

//        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener { parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
//            Log.d("Items Clicked","")
//            Toast.makeText(
//                activity,
//                titleList[groupPosition]
//                        + " : "
//                        + itemsList[titleList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition],
//                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//            false
//        }
    }
}
```

**My Adapter**

```
class DiscoverFilterAdapter internal constructor(
    private val context: Context,
    private val titleList: List<String>,
    private val itemsList: HashMap<String, List<String>>) : BaseExpandableListAdapter() {

    private var authorTextLive : MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getAuthorTextObserverable() : MutableLiveData<String> {
        return authorTextLive
    }

    override fun getGroupCount(): Int {
        return titleList.size
    }

    override fun getChildrenCount(groupPosition: Int): Int {
        return this.itemsList[this.titleList[groupPosition]]!!.size
    }

    override fun getGroup(groupPosition: Int): Any {
        return titleList[groupPosition]

    }

    override fun getChild(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Any {
        return this.itemsList[this.titleList[groupPosition]]!![childPosition]
    }

    override fun getGroupId(groupPosition: Int): Long {
        return groupPosition.toLong()
    }

    override fun getChildId(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Long {
        return childPosition.toLong()

    }

    override fun hasStableIds(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun getGroupView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        isExpanded: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val listTitle = getGroup(groupPosition) as String
        if (convertView == null) {
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_filter_list, null)
        }
        val titleText = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listTitle)
        titleText.text = listTitle
        return convertView

    }

    override fun getChildView(
        groupPosition: Int,
        childPosition: Int,
        isLastChild: Boolean,
        convertView: View?,
        parent: ViewGroup?
    ): View {

        var convertView = convertView
        val listItems = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition) as String
        if (convertView == null) {
            val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_filter_item, null)
        }
        val itemsText = convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.listItem)
        itemsText.text = listItems
        return convertView
    }

    override fun isChildSelectable(groupPosition: Int, childPosition: Int): Boolean {
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, Im alredy refer this link, I have added `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in Child XML and it really the solution.
Link:
[Android ExpandableListView and onChildClick not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555364/android-expandablelistview-and-onchildclick-not-working)